# Hamlet file and 18N

Tags: yesod

I'm having trouble adapting the generated site (yesod init) to use I18N. Specifically, I'm trying to use a localized string in the default-layout-wrapper.hamlet file that's generated, using `_{Msg...}`. I've changed Foundation.hs to say:

```
ihamletToRepHtml $(ihamletFile "templates/default-layout-wrapper.hamlet")
```

But I get the following error:

```
The function `pageHead' is applied to three arguments,
but its type `PageContent url0 -> HtmlUrl url0' has only two
In a stmt of a 'do' expression:
    pageHead pc _mrender[a522] _urender[a521]
```

I haven't touched the page content creation which says:

```
    pc <- widgetToPageContent $ do
        $(widgetFile "normalize")
        addStylesheet $ StaticR css_bootstrap_css
        $(widgetFile "default-layout")
```

So it looks like I need to adapt either the pc creation code or the calling code inside the hamlet template (the code that says for example `<title>#{pageTitle pc}`), but I have no idea how, and going through the API documentation and the various tutorials and blog posts didn't give me an answer (it's probably there, but I've missed it).

Any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can define a function like:

```
toHtmlUrlI hu _msgRender urlRender = hu urlRender
```

Then in `default-layout-wrapper.hamlet`, replace the embedding of `pageHead` with:

```
^{toHtmlUrlI $ pageHead pc}
```

What's happening is that since you're using ihamlet, the embedded template is expected to be of type:

```
type HtmlUrlI18n msg url = Translate msg -> Render url -> Html
```

However, `pageHead pc` is actually of type:

```
type HtmlUrl url = Render url -> Html
```

So you have to ignore that `Translate msg` parameter.

By the way, I think you can use `const` in place of `toHtmlUrlI`, but I find the latter to be a little bit clearer.

Comment: OK, this worked! I kinda like thought it was something like that... What seems weird is that I see to ignore the translate parameter, even though the content as well is going to be localized. I feel that I18N is not a integrated as it could be.